# What is the issue with transitive dependency in RDBMS?

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I was studying the article on Database Normalization 2NF in Wikipedia at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), when I came across the last example, on tournament winners. There it says that because there is a transitive dependency in the table, it is not in 2NF, and further optimization is needed (like splitting it into further tables) to restore that to 3NF and eliminating chances of data corruption. Can anybody tell me what kinds of 'corruption' can creep in to "show the same person from being shown with different dates of birth on different records"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine once you insert this row:

```
 Indiana Invitational   1998    Al Fredrickson  21 July 1975
```

and later you insert this (say, by mistake):

```
 Des Moines Masters     1999    Al Fredrickson  20 June 1985
```

As you can see, the same person has 2 different birthdays in this table. What that Wikipedia article says is that the birthday depends on the person, which is not a primary key. This means that the person can repeat and if you don't pay attention, its dependent attributes (such as birth date) can change.

What you should do is to make another table with the person name as primary attribute and move its dependent data over to that table (such as the person's birth date). This way, you will avoid the redundant `(name, birthday)` tuples and prevent possible corruption (as well as save memory).

Comment: Well, that's the point. The two tournaments can very well be won by two different persons with the same name Al Fredrickson, right? So why should it be an error? And secondly, user input data can be corrupt in a million ways, why devise a NF for each? Inserting a duplicate record is fatal enough, so the first 1NF, which forbids that, is reasonable. But why should there be a NF just to check whether the user data is incorrect?

Comment: That's what normalization does - removing redundancies and dependencies in the data. There may very well be two Al Fredricksons with different birthdates, but you have no way to tell if you keep them in the table with the winners. Better to have a `PERSON` entity that you can then use on the winner table.

Comment: Exactly as N West says. Removing redundancy by a better design (in higher normal form) also means that, instead of manually checking for user input, you leave it to the RDBMS. Probably a more important effect is the performance though. Imagine a huge data base of people and their belongings. If you don't distinguish the `Person`, `Thing` and `BelongsTo` tables, you would have a LOT of repeated data which both costs space and reduces search time.

Comment: I want to add that the issue with normalization is tied to how base data is stored and updated.  For a derived table, for a report, denormalization is fine.  You want the normalization where you are storing the master copy of the data.

Comment: Also, in this case, the name was assumed to be unique (which is not really in real life). In reality, the `Person` table will have a more complicated primary key.